# Best way to upload photos with php : Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, memory, upload, photo

On my website, there is the possibility for users to upload their own photos. The php code stores them in an image, makes a miniature, renames them and stores them on the website. The photos have to be <2MB, but a user recently told me he got this Fatal Error *"Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted"* when trying to upload a 900KB photo (which was, as you could guess, a big, wide, but well compressed JPEG).

On my shared hosting server I can't change the php.ini. The upload code currently looks like this :

```
            $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($value['tmp_name']);
            $width_source = imagesx($source);
            $height_source = imagesy($source);
            $max = max($width_source,$height_source);

            $ratio = $max/min($max,1000);
            $width_destination = $width_source/$ratio;
            $height_destination = $height_source/$ratio;
            $width_miniature = 100*$width_source/$height_source;
            $height_miniature = 100;

            $destination = imagecreatetruecolor($width_destination, $height_destination);
            $adress = '/home/photos/photo'.$id.'.jpg';
            imagecopyresampled($destination, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $largeur_destination, $hauteur_destination, $largeur_source, $hauteur_source);
            imagejpeg($destination, $adress);
            chmod($adresse, 0644);

            $miniature = imagecreatetruecolor($width_miniature, $height_miniature);

                                            etc etc to copy miniature
```

**Is there another way /method to upload large photos or to bypass php memory limit ?**

Comment: Why do you need `64MB` to resize a `900KB` image? That seems a bit excessive. Do you have a memory leak somewhere? Does it happen if you upload _just_ this image?

Comment: I've been looking for memory leaks (I didn't write the code myself, I took the website from someone else) but couldn't find one yet. 64MB is huge even for a big bmp...

It happens with other big images as well. I assume php stores them in a bmp. Recompressing them to 200KB does nothing but redimensionning them before uploading solves the problem.

Comment: For example I cant upload a 5000*4000 px, 1.3 MB image.
Same image, 2500*2000 px, 1MB, can be uploaded

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ini_set`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php) method to alter ini settings on the fly

```
ini_set('memory_limit','128M');
```

If you can't use this method, it will return false rather than setting the value.

Comment: I doubt shared hosting will allow you to change the memory limit. `64MB` seems like reasonable limit to me.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen; Fair comment, `ini_set` can be turned off (and likely will be, on shared hosting), but until the OP tries they won't know

Comment: I cant access php.ini, but i can try with htaccess

Comment: Appears as though you hosting has it locked down, in which case I doubt there is a way to bypass the limit.  Seems strange that you are getting an out of memory on `900KB` though, it looks like you hosting is set to `64MB`! Are you sure there isn't another possible problem?